# Arcade script for popup in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, arcade

I am new to Arcade and I am trying to build a Pop-up display in ArcGIS Online web map.

I have four Feature datasets in a map, one being a Local Government layer for the state.
I am trying to develop a popup that when clicking on an individual Local Government polygon, it will display the relevant count for each of the other 3 features for that polygon.

For example
Click on a Local Government polygon and the popup will display the count relevant to that Local Government Area of the other 3 feature data sets
Apples = 3
Orange's = 2
Pears = 0

Is this possible using Arcade?

Comment: Hi Toby. Good question, that other people should be able to help with. It's easier for other people to understand your question if you use less abbreviations. So try to use ArcGIS Online instead of AGOL and use unabbreviated version of LGA. Plus it could be nice if you clearly ask a question with a question mark instead of stating the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Davma I hope that's a little better

Answer (score 2):

What you ask is possible you need to be exploring the Arcade help file for the relevant commands, which are often accompanied with sample code.  I suggest you explore the [GetFeatureSet](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/data_functions/#getfeatureset) which has a sample code doing exactly what you want using the Intersects function.